# How to create offline forms that upload when internet access becomes available?

Tags: wordpress, forms, offline, buddypress

First of all, I have an employee portal that runs on WordPress, more specifically BuddyPress. I have forms that need to be filled out offline and then uploaded into the appropriate file location within Wordpress when internet connection becomes available. I guess it wouldn't be the end of the world if they had to manually upload them when internet was available, just so long as the form itself is available offline. But ideally automatic.

What are some ideas for approaches? I don't want to use any paid form services and also would rather not have the data in the forms be routed through any form builder company. I'd like to keep everything inside the company ecosystem.

Is there any way to cache the already-existing form in the portal or download the page on their device and simply hit the submit button once internet is available?

Comment: Progressive Web Apps - PWA.

Comment: As much as I'd love to dive into something that robust, I'm not really a programmer yet. Is there any way to just cache the form that we already have inside the employee portal or download the page on their device and simply hit the submit button once internet is available?

Comment: That’s exactly what a PWA does. It used to be simpler with the “Cache manifest” system about 8 years ago, but that was deprecated and removed and replaced with PWA.